# Want to create a div line between 2 other divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

[image]I want to create a separating line between 2 divs. But the line shows at the end of last div.

```css
.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="info_badge" id="teams_footer"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="info_badge" id="coinventor_footer">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There does not seem to be enough code in your question to ascertain what your problem might be. Might I suggest you expand the code in your example so that we can see how the CSS is currently positioning your elements?

Comment: There's quite a few libraries which can do this for you. Joint.js is very good: https://www.jointjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using `<hr/>` between the two divs like this?

```
<div></div>
<hr/>
<div></div>
```

And then add styles to it:

```
<hr style="width:50%;text-align:left;margin-left:0">
```

Comment: in between divs, a vertical line

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result without the extra `<div>` element

```html
<div class="col">
    <div class="info_badge" id="teams_footer"></div>
    <div class="info_badge" id="coinventor_footer">hello</div>
</div>
```

```css
.col > div:not(:last-child)::after
{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2px;
    height:20px;
    background:black;
}
```